# Weird a:visited behavior in IE8 for LI elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

For some reason, in IE only (tested so far on IE 8 with and without compatability mode), my visited links in an unordered list indent after being visited.

http://etech.916networks.com

My HTML (generated dynamically via PHP):

```
    <ul>
    <li>
    <a target='_blank' href='http://www.test.com/mylink.html' title='Systems Engineer'>Systems Engineer</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a target='_blank' href='http://www.test.com/mylink2.html' title='Validation Engineer'>Validation Engineer
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

My CSS (extra stuff in here trying to get it to work):

```
    #latest-updates li {
list-style-type: none;
list-style-image: none;
color: #3c758c;
padding-bottom: 4px;
list-style-position: outside;

    }

    #latest-updates a, a:visited {
list-style-type: none;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
text-indent: 0;
padding; 0;
margin: 0;
    }

    #latest-updates a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #25b6d6;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, this is driving me crazy!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second CSS block I believe you want.

```
#latest-updates a, #latest-updates a:visited
```

Otherwise you are applying that style to all 'a' tags in latest-updates plus all visited 'a' tags on the entire page.

Comment: That was it!  Awesome.  What I had going on was not only the above, but other references like  #nav a, a:visited  which were messing it all up.  Thanks Matthew!

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems before but not in IE8.

Try resetting the `margin` and `padding` on the parent element, which would be `ul`. So try adding this:-

```
ul{ margin:0; padding:0; }
```